# Is there any pre-builded sample code libraries for PIC18F14K50 using "XC8" Compilers only

Tags: microchip, pic18, xc8

I want to create an USB interface using PIC18F14K50. I have source code using c18 compiler but I want to update my firmware using XC8 (v1.37) compiler. I am using MPLAB X 3.25. Though the C compiler is giving me good results, I want to make my firmware forward compatible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download the current [Microchip Libraries for Applications](http://www.microchip.com/mplab/microchip-libraries-for-applications) from the vendor's website. Most (if not all) of the USB sample projects in the MLA compile with XC8 and build for the PIC18F14K50.

Comment: Ok...Thanks Jolati. :)